# Use an existing blob into a Media Services Asset (API v3)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I have large media files on Azure Storage block blobs, and I would like to encode them with Azure Media Service API **V3**.

I've found equivalent in API v2 : [Copying existing blobs into a Media Services Asset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-copying-existing-blob) but the v2 is obsolete and will be retired soon.

Where can I find exemple of Creating an Asset from an existing blob? All exemples I can find (including [offical SDK v3 tutorials](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet)) are always using small local videos uploaded directly.
Also, it's not clear if in V3 I still need to copy my blob to an asset like in V2, or if you can use a blob with an asset as long as the Media Service is using the same Storage Account (because as said in the v2 to v3 [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-v-2-v-3-differences-terminology), `AssetFiles` doesn't exists anymore in v3).

Answer (score 2):

I have a pretty extensive sample of copying content from a storage account, encoding it with AMS and delivering it back to the same location in this Node.js/Typescript sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_Bulk_Remote_Storage_Account_SAS

Take a look there first and tell me if that is what you are in need of.  There are a number of helper functions I use with the storage blob SDK in the common folder here.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/main/Common

Keep in mind that the workflow for remote assets can be achieved in a couple ways in v3.

1. V3 Jobs support the JobInputHTTP object, which can point to a read only SAS URL that you pass in from your remote storage blob (if the storage account is not attached to the AMS account).
2. You can create an empty Asset and copy the blob into it from a remote storage account and the submit the job as JobInputAsset as usual
3. You can create an asset and pass in the container name - if this is an attached storage account, you can then wrap an existing storage account container as an Asset and then submit a job with the specified file in that Asset container as the input source. This is what you said in the last sentence above... but it may not be clear that you can do this in JobInputAssets - look at the Files property on JobInputAsset to pass in a specific list of files to the encoder (single or multi if doing overlays).

"input": {
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.JobInputAsset",
"files": [],
"inputDefinitions": [],
"assetName": "job1-InputAsset"
},

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is clearly the 3. i am trying to achieve, but i don't know how. I see in the exemple it uses SAS urls, but how is it different from using url that are on a different provider? Why using absolute URLs? Will it download it first like a 'foreign' server, or will it use azure internal capabilities to read data?

Comment: If you provide a remote HTTP/S URL that we can access without authentication, the we will download the file to the encoder prior to running the job. That is the case when using  JobInputHTTP always.

Comment: I am trying to avoid Media Service to download (and consequently use transfer charges) files as if it was on an external network.

Comment: Inbound data in Azure is free... outbound data costs $